# JS Function to send data over network?

Tags: javascript, network-programming

I have been experimenting with JavaScript lately and was wondering if there was a way to send data from one computer to another on the same network. If there is, you do I use it?

Comment: I believe WebRTC supports peer-to-peer applications. http://www.webrtc.org

Comment: You will have to setup a server which can be done in node.js from there you can have your clients communicate over http.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, but you need a server for that. You cannot connect directly two computers' browsers over a network:

```
Computer A ---+
              |
             SERVER
              |
Computer B ---+
```

The server's task will then be that of passing messages from one client to the other. You'll need PHP or C# (*e.G.* ASP.NET) for that. This topic is very (very) broad so this must suffice as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go by a simple example of windows to windows communication. Go through the following link.

copy and paste server to server.js and client to index.html.

setup:

```
install socket.io
install client.io
```

link:

```
<https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_broadcasting.htm>
```